# How to use .RC files with assets in another folder

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have an `.RC` file in my project that looks like this:

```
MAINICON icon "c:\assets\app\icons\myicon.ico"
```

The file `c:\assets\app\icons\myicon.ico` exists, but when I compile the project, Delphi says:

> [BRCC32 Error] icon.rc(2): file not found: c:\assets\app\icons\myicon.ico

Looks like I need to follow some kind of rule to specify the complete path of my icon?

Comment: Odd. When I first viewed your question in the editor, I saw a hidden `U+0008` character between `c:` and ```\``` in the error message.  Now it's gone, but I don't see it in the question's history. Does that character exist in your `.rc` file? It is not visible in a web browser.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not visible on my ide. Your solution worked, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use double backslashes like this:

```
MAINICON icon "c:\\assets\\app\\icons\\myicon.ico"
```

You should consider using relative path.

Comment: You do not need to escape slashes in an RC file.